# Type declaration is not mandatory in TypeScript generics

Tags: typescript, generics

Short example of the issue I want to ask about in TypeScript:

```
export class Test {
    public runTest<T>(param: T): T {
        return param;
    }
}

let test1: Test = new Test();
test1.runTest<string>("string1");
test1.runTest("5555");
```

Both "runTest" statements will execute normally. First will require you to pass a string (which is great), second - not really. But I want to make it mandatory for anyone using "runTest" to pass some type into T.

Can it be done? Can't figure out a way to do it via code. Also tried looking for TSLint rule that could help, but also found none.

Thanks

Comment: Why mandatory? That's not how TypeScript works. `T` is inferred to be `string`. Type inference is one of TypeScript's fundamental features.

Comment: General idea is to make people always specify the type they are passing into method. Previous version was like runTest(param: any). I'd really like to always be written like runTest<IMessage>(message) where message is of IMessage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to get this done (I'm not going to worry about *why* you're doing this), you need to convince TypeScript to infer some bad type for `T` when you leave it out, so that it will fail to run the test.  I can't figure out how to do it directly, but here's an indirect way:

```
export class Test {
    public runTestIndirectly<T = never>(): (t:T)=>T {
      return (t:T)=>t  
    }
}
```

So `runTestIndirectly()` *produces* a function which behaves like `runTest`.  The type of `T` is inferred when you call `runTestIndirectly()`, which has no access to the type of object you pass to the function it produces.  And if you have `T` default to `never`, you will get a failure when you neglect to specify `T` to something that works:

```
let test1: Test = new Test();        
test1.runTestIndirectly<string>()("string1"); // works
test1.runTestIndirectly()("5555"); // fails:
// Argument of type '"5555"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Hope that helps!